# VPS Routing - packets over 1kb timeout

Tags: routing

I have a vps running on a Debian (Squeeze) which started to play funny 3 days ago. I can access it through ssh but all commands that lead to a network traffic of more than 1kb hang. ie: ls on a directory with a couple of files work but ls on a directory with many files hangs. Same goes for top, more, tail... and of course any data transfer through ssh, scp, ftp and web server traffic.
I have this problem from my local computer but also between my vps and other servers of the same host, also when trying to serve a page through an online screenshot tool.
Now at least 2 people have confirmed they could access it with no problem from different routes (2 different countries).
Host support (who have the same problems as me) just told me "wait until the network issue hopefully be solved" (by itself??). So here I am.

What can I do to try to diagnose the problem (and eventually suggest a solution to host support) ?
Thanks for your help

Update

After 4 days of denying there was a problem, datacenter finally solved the issue. Not sure what they did but noticed they have lower the MTU from 1500 to 1400. I guess they changed a device on their network that did not support previous packet size.
Thanks to all of you for your contribution.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/162062/126632

Comment: You should add the solution as an answer to the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a wild guess, but maybe the MTU configured in the VPS network adapter is larger than what their network actually supports. Perhaps you want to try something like:

```
ifconfig eth0 mtu 1500 up
```

`eth0`, `eth1` or whatever is the interface your VPS has with the Internet. 1500 is the default MTU for Ethernet networks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situations that was blamed on packet bursting.  Not sure if this applies, but wanted to share anyway.